# A series in the complex field from the math olympiads

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers, contest-math

I tried to do this exercise from the Senior selection test (A TST of Italy olympiad). The exercise is as follows:
Let  $z = \left ( 2 + i \right )$, where $i$ is the complex unity. Consider the integers $a_{n}, b_{n}$ such that $a_{n} + ib_{n} = z^{n} $.
Calculate the value of the serie $\sum_{0}^{\infty }\frac{a_{n}b_{n}}{7^{n}}$. I tried to bring me back to a geometric series, but the problem is that I can't make explicit the values ​​of $a_{n}, b_{n}$. I try to use the de Moivre's formula. Can you help me please? Thank you for your availability.

Comment: $z=\sqrt 5 e^{i\theta}$ where $\theta =\arctan (\frac 1 2)$. Write down $a_n$ and $b_n$ from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a_n + i b_n = (2 + i)^n$, then $a_n - i b_n = (2 - i)^n$, and so you have that
$$
  a_n = \frac{1}{2} \left((2 + i)^n + (2 - i)^n\right)
$$
and
$$
  b_n = \frac{1}{2i} \left((2 + i)^n - (2 - i)^n \right)
$$
and so
$$
  a_n b_n = \frac{1}{4i} \left((2 + i)^{2n} - (2 - i)^{2n} \right).
$$

This turns your sum into the difference of two geometric series:
$$
  \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{a_n b_n}{7^n} = \frac{1}{4i} \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{(2 + i)^2}{7} \right)^n - \frac{1}{4i} \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{(2 - i)^2}{7} \right)^n
$$

Using the formula for a geometric series, this is equal to
$$
  \frac{1}{4i} \left(\frac{1}{1 - \frac{3 + 4i}{7}} - \frac{1}{1 - \frac{3 - 4i}{7}} \right) = \frac{7}{4i} \left(\frac{1}{4 - 4i} - \frac{1}{4 + 4i}\right) = \frac{7}{4i} \cdot \frac{8i}{32} = \frac{7}{16}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

$z=\sqrt 5 e^{i\theta}$ where $\theta =\arctan (\frac 1 2)$. So $a_n=(\sqrt 5)^{n} \cos (n\theta)$ and $b_n=(\sqrt 5)^{n} \sin (n\theta)$.

Next use the fact that $\cos (n\theta)\sin (n\theta)=\frac 1 2 \sin (2n\theta)=\frac 1 2  \Im e^{2ni\theta}$. Finally, use the formula for a geometric sum.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I get the exact value of serie if I now only an approximation of $\theta =\arctan (\frac 1 2)$

Comment: The sum appears in terms of $e^{2i\theta}$. You can write down the exact value of $e^{2i\theta}$ from the fact that $\tan \theta =\frac 1  2$. No need to use approximate values.  @StCS

Comment: Thanks, I understand :)

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $$a_nb_n={1\over 2}{\rm Im}\,(a_n+ib_n)^2={1\over 2}{\rm Im}\,z^{2n}$$ Hence
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty {a_nb_n\over 7^n}= {7\over 2}{\rm Im}\,{1\over 7-{z^2}}$$